# I was there for two days or I was there two days?

Tags: grammar

Which variant is correct?

> I was there **for** two days.
>
> I was there two days.

And what about use for with stay?

> I stayed there **for** two days.
>
> I stayed there two days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preposition ***for*** is entirely optional in OP's exact context. My first thought was it makes no difference what the preceding verb is, but on reflection that's not quite right. Consider...

> 1: *I fed my neighbour's cat three days.*
>    2: *She listened five hours.*
>    3: *They paid the mortgage two decades.*
>    4: *He pestered her five days.*
>    5: *I read [a book] three hours.*

I don't like *any* of the above without ***for***. But I've no problem with...

> 5: *I've lived here twenty years.*
>    6: *We stayed six weeks.*
>    7: *They waited two hours.*
>    8: *He slept eight hours.*

I think the distinction turns on the fact that it's *acceptable* (but not *required*) to drop the preposition ***for*** before the time-frame **IF** the verb that it adverbially modifies implies some kind of *extended* action or state that inherently has a *duration*.